# pk de un objeto en una CreateView con vistas basadas en clases Django

Tags: django, django-models

Cordial saludo.

Estoy en una tabla con usuarios y al dar clic necesito que se lleve el pk del usuario seleccionado a un formulario donde se va a crear un libro, para que este libro quede relacionado al usuario.

¿Como puedo hacer este proceso o como funciona?

models.py

```
class Usuario(models.Model):
  Nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  Direccion = models.CharField(max_length=100)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.Nombre


class Libros(models.Model): 
   Nombre_Libro = models.CharField(max_length=30) 
   Guia = models.CharField(max_length=30)  
   IDUsuario  = models.ForeignKey(Usuario, null=True, blank=False, 
   on_delete=models.CASCADE)

   def __str__(self):
     return self.Nombre_Libro
```

forms.py

```
class LibrosForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Libros
    fields = ["Nombre_Libro", "Guia"]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super(LibrosForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
          for field in iter(self.fields):
             self.fields[field].widget.attrs.update({
               'class': 'form-control',
               'placeholder':field
            })
```

views.py

```
class CrearLibros(CreateView):
  template_name = 'libros.html'
  form_class = LibrosForm
  success_url = reverse_lazy('libros')
```

======ACTUALIZACIÓN======

Así quedo urls.py

```
url(r'^listado_usuarios/$',ListadoUsuarios.as_view(), name="listado_usuarios"),
url(r'^crear_libros/(?P<usuario>.+)$',CrearLibros.as_view(), name="crear_libros")
```

views.py

```
class CrearLibros(CreateView):
template_name = 'libros.html'
form_class = LibrosForm
success_url = reverse_lazy('libros')

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # Esto intenta obtener el valor de usuario, sino devuelve None
    id_usuario = request.GET.get('usuario')
    if id_usuario:
        # Intentamos recuperar ese usario desde la DB 
        usuario = Usuario.objects.get(id=id_usuario)
        # Ese get puede fallar, deberías capturar la excepción
        # Inicializamos el form con ese usuario ya cargado
        form = self.form_class(initial={'usuario': usuario})
    else:
        # Si no especificaron usuario en el request
        # mostramos el form vacio
        form = self.form_class()
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

url que llega a libros.html

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/crear_libros/1
```

libros.html

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">

                    <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</button>
            <h3>Libros</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

                        <h3>Ingresar Libro</h3>

                        <form role="form" action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}

                                <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Libros</label>

                                    {{ form.as_p }}

                                </div>         


                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
                                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset </button>

                            </form>             

                    </div>

            </form>
    </div>
```

El problema esta que cuando envío el form de libros.html no captura el id del usuario que va a crear el libro, entonces el libro queda sin creador.

Estoy enviando el id del usuario pero cuando creo el libro no he dado como capturarlo para relacionar el libro con el usuario.

El action del formulario esta vacío por que si lo envío a crear_libros me pide un pk y no se como ponerlo.

Yo vengo de php, normalmente esto se pone en un input type hidden, pero aquí ni idea.

Gracias por la ayuda!!!

Comment: Gracias mi amigo, excelente información. ¿Hay alguna forma de hacerlo con clases o necesariamente toca con funciones?

Comment: para realizar con clases puedes utilizar **get_form_kwargs** (https://chriskief.com/2012/12/18/django-modelform-formview-and-the-request-object/) puedes ver el ejemplo.

Answer (score 0):

Para eso deberías pasar el usuario como parámetro en la URL del vínculo, por ejemplo:

```
/crear_libro/?usuario=<id_usuario>
```

Luego deberías modificar un poco tu vista, para darle un comportamiento diferente al método GET. Algo más o menos así:

```
class CrearLibros(CreateView):
    template_name = 'libros.html'
    form_class = LibrosForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('libros')

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Esto intenta obtener el valor de usuario, sino devuelve None
        id_usuario = request.GET.get('usuario')
        if id_usuario:
            # Intentamos recuperar ese usario desde la DB 
            usuario = Usuario.objects.get(id=id_usuario)
            # Ese get puede fallar, deberías capturar la excepción
            # Inicializamos el form con ese usuario ya cargado
            form = self.form_class(initial={'usuario': usuario})
        else:
            # Si no especificaron usuario en el request
            # mostramos el form vacio
            form = self.form_class()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

Comment: Hola Pancho Jay agradezco tu ayuda, trate de seguir tus indicaciones, por favor puedes darle una mirada a una actualización que hice a la pregunta. Agradecería mucho tu ayuda. :)

Comment: @Vacanito hay varias formas de implementar lo que quieres. En la que yo te propuse no es preciso tocar el archivo de URLs ya que el parámetro llega en el querystring. Lo que tu propones también es válido, pero la implementación es un poco distinta, deberías modificar la vista para que espere usuario como un parametro de la URL.

Comment: Hola @Pancho Jay el problema es que no se como preparar la vista para que reciba el parametro. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

debes entender que en django ya todo esta escrito y lo que debes hacer es simplemente sobreescribir métodos o en la mayoría de los casos es así te pondre un ejemplo muy  pero muy sencillo de como relacionar el creador utilizando el Generic template el cual veo que estas utilizando. el ejempo es para que entiendas como trabaja django y así lo puedas adecuar a tu código

**usando generic templates y suponiendo que estás enviando bien el pk del autor y el formulario

```
from .models import LibrosForm
from django.views.generic import CreateView

class CrearLibros(CreateView):
    template_name = 'libros.html'
    form_class = LibrosForm
    success_url = '/libros/'

#Sobreescribimos el método y lo ajustamos para que antes de guardarlo en la base de datos django lo pueda relacionar
def form_valid(self,form):
    instance = form.save(commit=False) # este pequeño paso es la magia que necesitas
    instance.<tu_creador> = self.request.<tu_creador_que_viene_del_template> # ahora tu form ya tiene relacionado tu creador
    return super(CrearLibros, self).form_valid(form)
```

Espero que te sirva para entender un poquito más y logres dar con la solución definitiva saludos